# How to use getProperty() on Map<String, Map<String,String>> structure

Tags: java

I have created property object using below code -

```
import java.util.*;

public class setPropertyTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Map<String, String> mp1 = new HashMap<>();
       mp1.put("from", "somethingfrom");
       mp1.put("to", "somethingTO");

       Map<String, Map<String,String>> mp2 = new HashMap<>();
       mp2.put("testing", mp1);

       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.putAll(mp2);


   }
}
```

When I print properties, it prints to something like below-

```
{testing={from=somethingfrom, to=somethingTO}}
```

How do I retrieve the `from` key value out of properties object??

Comment: `properties.get("test).get("from")`. Properties is for... properties. I.e. if it had been designed properly, it wouldn't have let you store a Map as a value. If you want a Map as a value, you shouldn't be using Properties.

Comment: `Properties` is meant for String keys and values. Stick with `Map<String, Map<String, String>>`

Comment: `((Map) properties.get("testing")).get("from");`

Comment: Thanks, the solution works. But probably I will change the design a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-properties-class-java/) and commented by @ernest_k, Properties is designed for cases where the key is a String and the value is **also a String**.

To achieve what you want, try:

```
mp2.get("testing").get("from");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is NPE safe way to do this. `getOrDefault` is from Java 8

`mp2.getOrDefault("testing", Collections.emptyMap()).get("from")`

Answer (score 0):

As asked by OP, to get the `"from"` key value from Property object`(properties)`, we can do something like this

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.putAll(mp2);
    Object obj = properties.get("testing");
    if (obj instanceof Map) {
        Map<String,String> innerMap = ((Map<String, String>) obj);
        innerMap.get("from");
    }
```